# How to redirect to controller using jquery ajax in magento 2.3.5

Tags: ajax, jquery, magento2.3.5-p1, dynamic, custom-variable

I want to pass dynamic text-box value to controller using ajax, so if anyone have idea about it then please share with me.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please add more information to the question or add code which you've tried

Comment: Can you specify some more detail what you are trying to archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set below code in your phtml file to use ajax, You have to change your customurl in below code,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["jquery"],function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var customurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl().'frontname/index/index'?>";
                $.ajax({
                    url: customurl,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        customdata1: 'test1',
                        customdata2: 'test2',
                    },
                complete: function(response) {             
                    dateone = response.responseJSON.default_dateone;
                    datatwo = response.responseJSON.datatwo;         
                    console.log(datatwo+' '+dateone);   
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

inside your controller file execute() method,

```
    <?php
     use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
     protected $request;
    
    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        ...
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
      }
     public function execute()
        {
            $this->request->getParam('your_param'); // get ajax data here
        }
```